# Build a forum? Or buy forum addon? What about blog?

Tags: add-on, forum, addons

How simple is it to build a basic forum in EE? I assume Categories can be used for forum categories. Then create a channel "Forum Topics" with a "Message" field. Then perhaps use the Comment addon so everyone can comment on the forum topic? I'd like to be able to support search, as well. That means being able to search the entries in "Forum Topics" and the comments.

Or would it be easier to use an addon? I've taken a look at EE's forum addon. It's too full featured for what I need. Also, the markup, etc. is very messy. I'd need to integrate it with Twitter Bootstrap -- and maybe that's too huge of an undertaking. Maybe it's easier to just build something on my own?

Thoughts?

NOTE: If I were to build a blog, would I take the same approach? A simple Channel with a "content" field, Comments addon, and maybe a tag addon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the forum you could use the Ellis Lab add on. I've used it a couple of times and can't say I'm a fan but it will do the job and you can template it as simple or as complex as you need (there's a good starting template framework around I believe). To be honest I'd probably look at using some non-EE solution unless you needed member integration between the Forum and other parts of the site.

Blogs are simple with EE. Do it like you suggest and use the Comments module to handle your comments. There are some good examples in the EE docs on how to do this.

Comment: Couldn't I do the exact same thing with forums?

Comment: Depends on the level of functionality you require. Forums are typically threaded conversations so you *could* do it with comments I suppose.